# Examining the .NET heap at runtime

Tags: .net, api, memory, silverlight, heap-memory

Is there any way to walk the heap from a .NET application? I have a Silverlight application and want to be able to examine the heap for memory leaks. I thought it would be nice to implement a debugging popup window that would display the contents of the heap. I have looked through the .NET API namespaces and can't find anything relevant.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [SOS Debugging Extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb190764.aspx) to examine the managed memory allocations in your program.

Here is [a blog post walking through how to do this with Silverlight](http://blog.ningzhang.org/2008/12/silverlight-debugging-with-windbg-and.html).

Comment: windbg + SOS.dll can be quite intimidating at first; however they are a great set of tools to become familiar with for this type of inspection as well as post-mortem debugging of crash heaps

Answer (score 0):

You can also try the [SysInternals's](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/default) tool [ProcessExplorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653). It have a tab named .NET where you can find a lot of specific data about .NET applications (memory, garbage collector activity, etc). Every time I suspect that my code is leaking memory I use this tool to check and understand what is happening.